# Is it possible to Make UBUNTU portable on my HHD

Tags: 14.04, external-hdd, portable

Hello is it possible to fully install ububtu in an EXTERNAL HDD and then work on my UBUNTU as long as i take my HDD. A portable OS fully installed on a external HDD

Comment: Yes, it's possible :-)

Comment: yes it is. You can find all the info here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just install it on Portable HDD, and you'll have no problems.

Comment: You can even allocate how much disk space for Ubuntu OS. You may want to install additional drivers so your portable Ubuntu OS can handle any PC.